# How to edit WSDL (XML) in SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis, wsdl

is there a way to edit the xml file during the package?
I have WSDL file and 1 table with 1 column (short int) in MSSQL.
In SSIS I have foreach loop container which has every iteration different value from my 1 the msssql table.
And this value (value in variable) I need to paste into WSDL file and get response from WSDL.

Is there an easy way to do this?

For example:

**start xml....
< Number>?< /Number>
end xml....**

And during execution of package insert my variable instead of a question mark?

Like this - first iteration of my foreach loop:

**start xml....
< Number>1< /Number>
end xml....**

..
get answer from WSDL
..
Second iteration of my foreach loop:

**start xml....
< Number>2< /Number>
end xml....**

Thank you,
J

Answer (score 2):

When you configure your web service task, in the input and output tabs you can specify that you want to use variables.  For the input tab there is a checkbox to specify a variable instead of a value, while  in the output tab you can specify the output type as a variable. You can read about it in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/web-service-task?view=sql-server-ver15) or see this tutorial for some images: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-web-service-task/

[image]

[image]

Finally, I should point out that you are not invoking the WSDL, you are invoking a SOAP web service. The WSDL serves another purpose. See this article for an explanation: [The WSDL is not the SOAP web service](https://d-petre-bogdan.medium.com/the-wsdl-is-not-the-soap-web-service-97f307c4a90b).

So you don't edit the WSDL or the XML, the SSIS web service task handles the SOAP protocol for you, and allows you to call a method on the web service by sending it some parameters, in your case the number of each iteration.